# How do I access the scroll bar on a box in selenium using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm starting out with Selenium using C# in Visual Studio and so far so good. However on the site I'm building tests for, there's a dialog box with text and a scroll bar on the right side. I have to scroll it to the bottom for another button to become enabled for me to click to. The best example of cases like this are end user agreements where you have to read the text (scroll to bottom) for accept to become enabled.

The code for it is all front-end so I'm wondering if I have to call Javascript methods somehow for this?

I was reading about JavascriptExecutor but I have no idea how to get this set up in Visual Studio / C#. If anyone has some examples, I would greatly appreciate it!